# strdup dumping core on passing NULL

Tags: c, linux, compiler-construction, posix, freebsd

strdup(null) dumps core.

Tried in on ubuntu and freeBSD both.

why? Shouldn't it return null?

```
char *b = NULL;
a = strdup(b);
```

This will dump core on strdup call.

Comment: Why should it return `NULL`? It's not standard. It can be implemented however the library writers like.

Comment: Not if the library writer wants to conform to posix, where strdup is a standard function though.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

That's quite ok.

The [documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html) implies that it's argument must be string, if it's something else, such as a null pointer, it's anyones guess what'll happen. In essence, you get undefined behavior when passing a NULL pointer to strdup.

It's quite normal for functions to yield undefined behavor if you pass them something you're not supposed to. Many standard C function such as strcpy, strlen does not accept null pointers either.

Answer (score 7):

[`strdup` returns NULL in case of allocation failure.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html)

This is not allocation failure.  The behavior when a wild pointer is passed in is undefined.  You're required to pass in a valid pointer to a NUL-terminated string.

Comment: @chux: Thanks for the heads up, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I think that it is [expected behaviour](http://unix.derkeiler.com/Mailing-Lists/FreeBSD/hackers/2008-04/msg00153.html).

Answer (score 1):

Of course, all the answers are correct. Nonetheless, in case of strdup(), it would be nice to have it to be able to deal with null pointers, too - just return a "null" string too, in that case. Of course, it is easy to define a strdupnullok() function with that behaviour as a wrapper around strdup(), but it is then an additional wrapper and function call, so makes code a tiny bit slower.