# How to Parse a String coming from a Client into an exec()?

Tags: c, parsing, pipe, exec

i have a Client-Server communication based on pipes and i'm reading user input and then writing into the pipe, sending what the user has typed into the Server. Then on the server i have this:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]){

    int fd;

    if((fd = open("fifo", O_RDONLY)) < 0){
        perror("open");
        exit(1);
    }

    char buf[100];  
    int bytes_read = 0;

    while((bytes_read = read(fd, buf, 100)) > 0){
        execute_command(buf);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So now i have the command that the user sent on the buf array and i call the execute_command function that has the following code:

```
void execute_command(String command){
     int status;
     pid_t pid;
     char** argv = split(command);

     if( !(pid = fork()) ){
        execlp(argv[0],argv[0],argv + 1);
        _exit(-1);
     }
     else
         wait(NULL);
     }
}

static char** split(char* command){
    int i = 0;
    char** argv = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 100);

    char* c = strtok(command, " ");
    while( c ){
        c = strtok(NULL," "); 
        argv[i++] = strdup(c); 
    }
    argv[i] = 0;

    return argv;
}
```

When running this, whenever i send something from the client side, i get "Segmentation fault (core dumped) on the server side. I'd assume it's because i'm using the char arrays and pointers in the wrong way... I'm still trying to understand all this pointer things in C. Also, communication needs to be based on Pipes, can't be using sockets like some people already told me. The only thing i can really change is the declaration of the variables related to the strings and the type of the exec().

Comment: Note that the message on the pipe probably does not end with a null byte, so you likely aren't working with strings.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't actually compile, because (1) you didn't show us your `#include`s, and (2) you have two stray `}`s (one after `execute_command(buf);` and the other after `wait(NULL);`). Please post the exact code you're actually running.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [strdup dumping core on passing NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432384/strdup-dumping-core-on-passing-null)

Comment: If the duplicate question itself isn't a big enough hint, in the last iteration of the loop in `split`, `c` is `NULL` when you call `strdup(c)`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in `execlp(argv[0],argv[0],argv + 1);`.

`execlp` expects a *list* (not an array) of `char *` arguments, terminated by `NULL`, as in

```
    execlp("foo", "bar", "baz", NULL);
```

You (1) pass a `char **` as a last argument, and (2) there is no terminating `NULL` in your argument list.

Since you already prepared an array of arguments, use `execvp` instead.

Comment: So how would i call the execvp()?                                                                          
                                                                                                                                            `execvp(argv[0], argv+1) ` ?

Comment: Do not `argv + 1`. The program you called will be confused. Use `execvp(argv[0], argv)`.

Comment: Still getting the Segmentation fault (core dumped) :(